# How to arrange 20 flags in 12 masts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Can anyone help me with this problem?

> We have 20 flags to be put in 12 masts, each mast can hold 20 flags
> and all the flags can be in the same mast, but all flags must be used.
> The order of the flags matters. How many ways can we arrange the
> flags?

I am having trouble counting all the possibilities can anyone give me a insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the order of the masts matters -- i.e. the masts are distinguishable.

Temporarily imagine that the flags are identical. Then by standard stars and bars the number of ways to do it is $C(31,11)$

[throw in $12$ additional flags, put them in a line, then choose $11$ from the $31$ interior gaps which writes $32$ as an ordered sum of $12$ positive integers, then subtract $1$ from each entry which writes $20$ as an ordered sum of $12$ non-negative integers].

Now given ONE such arrangement of "how many flags on each mast", there are simply $20!$ linear orderings of the flags (say bottom to top on each mast, left-to-right for the masts themselves) each of which gives a unique arrangement of the distinct flags on the masts with the given arrangement of "how many flags on each mast".

In other words, each desired arrangement consist of unique pair: (1) an ordered sum of $12$ non-negative integers adding to $20$, and (2) a linear ordering of the $20$ flags (since the order of the flags within each mast matters)

So $C(31,11)(20!)$ altogether.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Start with any permutation of the $20$ flags. Break it into $12$ segments, some of which can be empty. That completely determines an arrangement of the flags on the masts, and each arrangement of the flags on the masts completely determines such a permutation and its division into $12$ segments. Now, how many permutations are there? How many ways are there to insert $11$ divisions to break it into $12$ segments?